# jQuery basic plugin not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have copied the basic plugin from jQuery's website.
Now, when I put this code into a file and load it into my app, the plugin does not work. I cannot access the plugin via `$.` but can seen to access it via `$.fn.` (which seems strange to me). Here is how I'm loading the scripts (I don't see anything).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

And here's what's inside of `plugins.js`

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;
}
```

I have even tried the following:

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        color: "#556b2f",
        backgroundColor: "white"
    }, options );

    // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
    return this.css({
        color: settings.color,
        backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
    });

}; }( jQuery ));
```

But this does not seem to work either. Nor does the console present any errors.

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/btsoq4rj/1/

Comment: I have no idea what is going on. It's not working when I call it from `index.js` and it doesn't work in the console. I would presume it has nothing to do with `index.js` as it's loaded before `plugins.js`

Comment: how are you calling it...

Comment: `$('#almightyGreen').click(function(){ $.greenify('.peasants'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you can calling the plugin it should be

```
$('#almightyGreen').click(function () {
    $('.peasants').greenify();
});
```

Your code `$.greenify('.peasants');` is trying to call a function which is referred by `$.greenify` which does not exists in the code you have shared.